How to prove that the second derivative of $\sqrt x + \sqrt y = 2$ is $y'' =1/x^{2/3}$?
I'm trying to prove that for the equation $\sqrt x+\sqrt y=2$, the second derivative $y′′$ is $\dfrac1{x^{2/3}}$ I have reached the expression:
$$y''=\frac{-\left(-\sqrt{y/x}\cdot x-y\right)}{2x^\frac32\sqrt y}$$
but I can't simplify it to $y''= \dfrac1{x^{2/3}}$.
Could someone help me understand how to proceed to reach that form?
Thank you for the help.

Remember $y=\left(2-\sqrt x\right)^2$.

It seems that you didn't even try to simplify. For example, why don't write $$y''=\frac{\sqrt{y/x}\cdot x+y}{2x^\frac32\sqrt y}$$ instead of $$y''=\frac{-\left(-\sqrt{y/x}\cdot x-y\right)}{2x^\frac32\sqrt y}$$


I have reached the expression:
$$y''=\frac{-\left(-\sqrt{y/x}\cdot x-y\right)}{2x^\frac32\sqrt y}$$
but I can't simplify it to $y''= \dfrac1{x^{2/3}}$.

What did you do to get that mess? I mean, it is correct, but getting there is unobvious.
Anyway, to simplify, just cancel the common factor ($\surd y$) and use $\surd y=2-\surd x$ to tidy up the numerator, then cancel the common $2$.
$$\begin{align}\dfrac{-(-\surd(y/x)\cdot x-y)}{2x^{3/2}\surd y}&=\dfrac{\surd x+\surd y}{2x^{3/2}}\\&=\dfrac 1{x^{3/2}}\end{align}$$

A cleaner method is to simplify after the first derivation.
$\begin{align}\tag 1\surd x+\surd y&=2\\\tag 2 y^{1/2}&=2-x^{1/2}\\\tag 3y^{-1/2}y'&=-x^{-1/2}\\\tag 4y'&=-(2-x^{1/2})x^{-1/2}&\mbox{by }(2)\mbox{ if }x^{1/2}\neq 2 \\\tag 5y'&=1-2x^{-1/2}\\\tag 6y''&=x^{-3/2}&\mbox{defined on }x\in(0;2)\end{align}$

$y''=\frac{1}{x^{\frac{3}{2} } } $
proof:
$y''=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{y}{x} }x+ y}{2x^{\frac{3}{2} } \sqrt{y} } 
 (x> 0 , y> 0)$
$y''=\frac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y} }{2x^{\frac{3}{2} }  } $
$y''=\frac{1}{x^{\frac{3}{2} } } $

Are you sure his answer is right?

Maybe,his question is wrong!Do you treat the question carefully?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
